# DOT complaint for non US citizen

Tags: air-travel, usa, europe, legal, cancellations

I'm non-US citizen. I planned a trip to US this summer and booked several (separate) tickets. One of my tickets has recently been canceled with just saying I can rebook that flight. Fortunately I found out that there is the DOT for flights from or to US. But I cannot figure out if this is only possible for US citizens or also for Europeans.
I found [this](http://www.dot.gov/airconsumer/air-travel-complaint-comment-form) form on their site, but there is no field to enter the country and I can only select a state within the US.
Is it possible for me to file a DOT complaint? If yes, how should I enter my data?

Comment: You can presumably enter your complaint like everyone else. The “state” field can be “other” and address isn't even mandatory. But what do you expect from this?

Comment: DOT? Department of Transportation I assume?

Comment: Did you have insurance? usually that's the only recourse people have for cancelled flights - it's often deep in their fine print.

Comment: Did you look up the US rules for flight cancellations? Last-minute cancellations by the airline are indeed probably not allowed without giving you the right to re-book without an additional charge. However, a flight cancellation >2 months into the future *may* actually be allowed by US laws (or the DOT's interpretation of them).

Comment: @sailingthoms - Hey, did you actually call the airline to check if they will rebook you to a different flight free of charge? Many major airlines will do that. It doesn't make any sense to file a complaint before having tried that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flight schedules get changed all the time, some flights get cancelled, others get added.  There is no law against it and no compensation available simply because they cancelled a flight.

As your flight is in the future, they have to give you a couple of choices: One you can cancel your booking and get your payment refunded; Two you can choose an alternate flight schedule between the two cities on the same airline.

If alternate times exist on the same day, the airline will usually automatically rebook you on another flight that day. If the flights goes only once a day or if they are dropping that city pair, then you will have to contact them in regard to how you wish to proceed.

As of this point, based on your posted details, the airline has done nothing wrong so there are no grounds that DOT can act upon.  And rather than complaining to DOT you are better off getting in touch with the airline right away to see if an alternate time works for your vacation plans or cancelling completely and getting your money back.  Sooner is better than later, because everyone else on the cancelled flight will be trying to grab alternate flights.  And your window of opportunity for getting a refund is not open ended.